# Desktop and Documents folder invisible in finder, but visible with ls command

Tags: macos

As the title said, my Desktop and Documents folder doesn't appear in finder when i'm in the path /users/[username]

But however :

```
$ ls /users/[username]
Applications    Qt              workspace
Desktop         Movies          
Documents       Music
Downloads       Pictures
Library         Public
```

How is that possible ?

Comment: What do you mean "invisible in Finder?"  Can you post a screenshot of where it doesn't show up?

Comment: I mean he is not visible at all, like if he wasn't here.

Comment: Did you activate Documents & Desktop in iCloud?

Comment: I check, they're.

Comment: Can you press cmd + shift + . and try running `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder`?

Comment: The commands show all the files that start with a dot obviously, and also Desktop and Document (as the others with a reduce opacity) even if they don't start with a dot.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal behavior if you have activated Desktop & Documents Folders syncing in iCloud (as @pjc90 has mentioned in the comments).

[image]

Comment: Desktop & Documents Folders are not even in this iCloud window

Comment: @Pixeuh Desktop & Documents are the first item on the list.